# Strange behaviour when type-hinting dict.items() in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

Say I have a function, `do_something`:

```
from typing import Sequence, Tuple, Dict

def do_something(argument: Sequence[Tuple[int, str]]):
    pass
```

Say I also have a dictionary, `D`, the keys of which are solely `int`s, and the values of which are solely `str`s:

```
D: Dict[int, str] = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

In PyCharm, this will pass the type-checker with flying colours:

```
do_something(
    ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'))
)
```

But this, according to PyCharm, fails the type-checker, despite being identical in what it produces:

```
do_something(tuple(D.items()))
```

Is this expected behaviour -- am I missing something here? -- or is this a bug with PyCharm's type-checker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in PyCharm.
There are many similar bugs, e.g. [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43912), [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35026), [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35038).

In general, PyCharm is pretty clever about this. It correctly infers the type of `D` in your case. It also correctly infers `D.items()`, and then in code like `for k, v in D.items()`, `k` and `v` will be correctly inferred. But for some strange reason, `tuple`/`list`/`sorted` or sth around `D.items()` is buggy.

I would always report an issue on [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) when you would expect that it should work.

Comment: I'd still be curious to know whether Mypy is fine with this.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm can't guarantee the type of `D` to really be `Dict[str, int]`; it probably doesn't do code flow analysis to make sure nothing can't have added a non-`(str, int)` pair into the dict. (As an aside, you should see if Mypy, the "canonical" type checker for Python, can.)

You might be able to add the explicit type annotation to see if that helps.

```
D: Dict[str, int] = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Yes -- I tried explicitly specifying that the dictionary's keys and values would always be of consistent types. Nothing doing, sadly (though it's obviously not a massive issue).

Comment: If adding the explicit type doesn't help, it's possible there's no implicit or explicit typing saying `tuple(x.items())` for an `x` that is `Dict[K, V]` is a `Sequence[Tuple[K, V]]`...

Comment: Yes, I think it is a deeper problem. I tried adjusting the type-hints in the function itself to:

```def DoSomething(argument: Sequence[Tuple[Any, Any]]):
 pass```

and the problem is still there. No matter what the types of the keys and values of any given dictionary, it seems to me that tuple(Dict.items()) will always be of type Sequence[Tuple[Any, Any]]. So this just doesn't make logical sense to me.

Comment: Hmmm... Try `Iterable[Tuple[K, V]]` - I think `Sequence`s are supposed to be indexable, but `.items()`es certainly aren't.

Comment: Still a no! Judging from the examples I've been pointed to in the other answer, it looks like it probably is just a PyCharm bug.